# F250 Tag to Match F-150 and F-350 Tags

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

I know this is very anal of me, but was looking to get the [f250](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/f250) tag to match the [f-150](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/f-150) and [f-350](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/f-350) tags. The dash (-) is missing. Stupid, I know, but just thinking it needs to be standardized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

F250 is gone and F-250 has taken it's place.

Comment: I will accept this as the answer ... as soon as it will let me :-) Thanks, Larry!

Comment: @Paulster2 it won't let you accept the answer?

Comment: I had just gone through and accepted a couple of other answers here in the Meta, so wouldn't let me do it for another 9 minutes (at that time). I just waited until I got home from work and all is now golden :D